# Как правильно получить текст?

Tags: php, безопасность

Есть

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

Получаю данные

```
$data = $_REQUEST['name'];
```

Но если я введу в поле для ввода, ' то sql запрос не работает.

**Вопрос**: как правильно и безопасно получать текст? (И с html разметкой, и без.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $data = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['name']);
```

Comment: pdo, плейсхолдеры? не, не слышал

Comment: @FLK, вот как раз для вас, я и оставил такую возможность, чтоб поведать об этом ТС. Сейчас вы все аккуратненько распишите и я буду первый, кто поставит вам +1

Comment: благодарю, за предоставленную возможность, но лениво как то то же самое по 20 раз писать. учитывая ваш уровень ответов, на другие вопросы, не ожидал, что будете рекомендовать подобные решение.

Comment: @FLK, Мне лень тоже не чужда.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(htmlspecialchairs($_REQUEST['name'])));
```

Comment: что!!!??? ты хоть понял что сделал?

Answer (score 0):

тогда уж можно для верности в `htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");` загнать (кодировку и строку подставляйте свои)

ЗЫ пора уже на mysqli переходить )